# Can we override the spring beans declared in one xml config in another config?

Tags: java, spring

I am a newbie to Spring so this question might have an easy answer so please bear me if i'm asking something silly.

I have a global spring config file which I want to use in many applications and I would like to override some properties of few beans differently in different applications. Can you suggest the best way to do this?

For example, I've something like this in `global.xml`.

```
<bean id="testInstance" class="testClass">
    <property name="mem1" ref="val1"/>
    <property name="mem2" ref="val2"/>
</bean>
```

Now, I want to refer `testInstance` from a different spring config and use it after overriding `mem1`. Is it possible in spring? Do i need to use custom tags for that?

Comment: You can, but you then need to override the testInstance. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849192/springs-overriding-bean)

Comment: Use search first! :) Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849192/springs-overriding-bean And this: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/overriding-spring-beans/

Answer (score 4):

You can override a bean defined in xml in another xml config. But if you want to leverage @Configuration to do same then you are out of luck. Spring does not allow to do that.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9567

Comment: this issue is now fixed