# Why is overriding spring bean declared in one config allowed in another config?

Tags: java, spring

I am starting to learn Spring and came across a feature of Spring - [overriding spring bean declared in one xml config in another config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093768/can-we-override-the-spring-beans-declared-in-one-xml-config-in-another-config).

I do not understand where this feature can be useful. It seems illogical because same container will be configured using two different xmls and even when there are two beans with same ID, instead of reporting the ambiguity it is defaulting to the last one.

Is there a practical scenario where this can actually be useful? Is this good practice?

Comment: Testing, developing component libraries. Giving sensible defaults and allow users to override. There are numerous occasions features like this can be useful. Spring is also reporting the fact that a bean is getting overridden, this can also be disabled but that would require you to override/extend some default spring components.

Comment: @M.Deinum You should make this as an answer.

Comment: And to add to that: there are lots of frameworks (like Spring Security) that define a lot of default beans. If you were not able to override beans, you would not really be able to customize such frameworks easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reasons why this could be useful for instance

- Testing
- Developing Component Libraries

### Testing

When testing you can choose to override 1 or more beans. For instance a `DataSource` you probably don't want to test against the production instance of your database. But maybe an in memory one or one specially for testing. For this you can then just override the `DataSource` bean.

### Developing Component Libraries

You can provide a starting configuration for your libraries and let users override certain components or let them implement interfaces. A sample of this is how the different Spring portfolio projects work (Spring Security, Spring Batch) with their default configuration.

Also when overriding beans spring will log this at startup of your application.