# What happen when we call new Bean() where Bean is singleton?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Hi All this can be duplicate question sorry for that but i was not able to find that post.

Question :- Suppose there is a class A which has been written in this way

```
  @Component
  public class A{}
```

Now when i call A a = new A() two times will it provide me same object or not ?
This may be stupid question but Can you please clarify it in details ?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have a Bean when using the `new`keyword yourself, you have a POJO. A Bean implies that the object is created by the container. This said, the bean container will always return the same bean. Using `new`, you would have to implement the singleton pattern on the POJO or you will end up with different objects.

Comment: in a singleton, you shouldn't be able to call the constructor from outside the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `A = new A()` in your example, you'll get a new instance, always, because A is not implemented as a singleton class.

The fact that it is anotated as @Component will only affect that class when it is instanced in the spring context, and a variable instantiated with `= new()` (there are exceptions, but lets generalize) is not in the spring context.

If you want to always have the same bean, you should instantiate your variable "a" with @Autowired, in the following way:

```
@Autowired
private A a;
```

Also note that @Autowired will only work if the current class is, too, in the spring context (you didn't instantiate it with a =new(...)).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I don't want to instantiate same object or use injection, I was just want to clear this doubt that will spring singleton will work as java singleton class or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this one is Singleton class example and you cannot instantiate it with new keyword from outside of class because your constructor is private.

```
 class MySingleton
{
    static MySingleton instance = null;
    public int x = 10;

    // private constructor can't be accessed outside the class
    private MySingleton() {  }

    // Factory method to provide the users with instances
    static public MySingleton getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)        
             instance = new MySingleton();

        return instance;
    } 
}
```

Secondly, you can find lots of information in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html) about Bean and you need to create bean with `@Bean` annotation for example.

Besides, you can look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993181/defining-the-same-spring-bean-twice-with-same-name)

Comment: "you cannot instantiate it with new keyword." this is a bit incomplete, seeing as you instantiate it with the new keyword as well. a more complete explanation: "you cannot instantiate it with new keyword from outside of it's own class"

Comment: This is not a singleton class this is a singleton bean, there are many difference in java class and spring bean.