# I need 2 endpoint mapping beans with the same id

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws, endpoint, endpoints

let's say my app has a feature which can be enabled or disabled:

- if disabled, spring beans (including endpoint mappings) will be loaded from main.xml
- if enabled, spring beans (including endpoint mappings) will be loaded from main.xml *and* extra.xml.

The problem is my endpoint mapping has an id of "mynamespaceEndpointMapping". This bean is of the type org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping.

How do i define this bean in such a way that when it's loaded from main.xml it has only one endpoint but when it's loaded from extra.xml it has 10 endpoints? (I don't want all the 10 endpoints defined in main.xml if i have no use for them there) I could use bean inheritance but this would break the namespace naming convention since i would probably need different ids for the beans...

Thanks,
Teo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the spring bean. Like in this answer: [Spring's overriding bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849192/springs-overriding-bean)

But this is only possible with XML configuration and not with annotations.

EDIT: I meant the accepted answer. But I tested it with my own code.

I got 2 id's. In test1.xml

```
<bean id="test" class="Test1" />
```

and in test2.xml

```
<bean id="test" class="Test2" />
```

During startup is use both "test1.xml", "test2.xml" (in that order) in the ApplicationContext en when I get the Spring bean *test* it's of class Test2.

Comment: Yes but in that snippet of code the beans have different ids. Don't i need the same id for it to qualify correctly as an endpoint mapping?

Comment: This is indeed a solution, though i was hoping for something that would not depend on the order.